# The query contained only ignored words OleDbException using Index Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbexception, indexing-service

I have **ASP.NET 4.6.1 WebForms Legacy** that using **Index Server** in **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

I get  **OleDbException**  error with message:

> ```
> The query contained only ignored words.
> ```

My code:

```
 var datos = new List<Documento>();
 var sql = "Select DocAuthor, vpath, doctitle, FileName, Path, Write, Size, Rank, Create, Characterization, DocCategory from " + Settings.Default.NombreCatalogoIndexServer + "..Scope() where " + FunctionContains(texto) + " order by rank desc";

            using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, "Provider=MSIDXS;"))
            {
                using (var testDataSet = new DataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(testDataSet, "SearchResults");
                    using (var catalogo = testDataSet.Tables[0])
```

Full error:

**System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80041605):**

The query contained only ignored words.

> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)  at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)  at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)  at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)  at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)  at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable)

Keys:

1. How can I remove all noise ?
2. How can I configure Index Server for Spanish culture ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: See this https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21346813/The-query-contained-only-ignored-words-MS-Indexing-Service.html

Comment: I'm ***confused*** yet, **`not useful`** for me